# VBA - Combining modules

Tags: excel, vba, dll, module, libraries

I am trying to build my own library in VBA by creating several modules, which depend on each other.
This means you can only use the main part of this, if you import all modules.

Since there are more than just a few modules, it does not make sense to export them as .bas-files and import them in other projects.

Now my questions is, if there is a (more) convenient way for combining modules (for example into a library-object, like a .jar-file in java).

Thanks for your time and help.

I understand that you can merge all functions from all modules into one big single module, but this stays in conflict with all software-engineering-principles and (of course is no good practice).

Comment: How big is your typical module? You might need to take a long hard look at how the code is divided amongst the various modules and their interdependencies if you want it to be useful as a library without having to bring along the kitchen sink every time. You can turn it into an add-in when it is stable like the Excel solver.xlam for instance.

Comment: Are you confusing the term "Module" with "Class" or "Function" Single Responsibility Principle does not apply to a module. If the functions are not inter-related then why do they have such tight dependencies

Comment: As VBA is not really object-oriented like Java (it contains class-modules, but they are more inconvenient to use) I try to see a module as class. From my point of view it does not make sense to put 100 functions into one module, if some of them are about Range-Objects, others about Filesystem-Objects and then other ones for specific operations on arrays. Don't know if this makes sense

Comment: This doesn't bode well 'by creating several modules, which depend on each other.'.  You can certainly build project hierarchies but if projects depend on each other then combine them to remove the dependency.

Comment: Okay, maybe I didn't explain it good enough. I have a VBA-Project with lets say 10 Modules. Some of them can be used without using other modules, so it makes sense to put them into their own module, or even into an own project, right? Now, is it possible in VBA to import multiple modules by putting them into any container,? Or in other words: can you create a .dll file via vba?

Comment: You can create a number of xlam or other worksheets and reference them.  If you want an activex dll then you'll have to use twinBasic, the up and coming replacement for VBA.  https://twinbasic.com/preview.html

Comment: Thank you all, an .xlam-file will just do the trick - just seems a bit „unprofessional“ from my point of view…

Comment: I write in the top of the module what other modules are required to cover _all_ functions in the module. Example from my [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date/blob/master/DateSpan.bas).